# Disable Home Button programmatically for Android 4.4.4

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to disable the Home Button programmatically on a Honeywell CT50 which has Android Version 4.4.4 (API 19). I have tried several codes posted by other but none of them seem to work.Please help. Thank you

Comment: I don't think it possible.

Comment: It is a android security violation.

Comment: You can't disable it. Unless you build your own Android custom OS. But that's a really bad idea in terms of user experience

Comment: `@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}` have u tried this?

Comment: It is not possible. There is a reason the Home button is harder to disable than other keys.

Comment: @Charuka Yes I have tried that code before. It says "Cannot Resolve Symbol 'TYPE_KEYGUARD' ". I read about this code in another page in which another user had the same problem and that he changed it to TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG and it worked for him. I tried changing it to that but it said "Unfortunately, (app's name) has stopped."

Comment: Just for the dumb idea in general, I gave you a -1. Why in the world would you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Toddler Lock just uses a BroadcastReciever and listens for Intent.ACTION_MAIN and the category Intent.CATEGORY_HOME - that's why when you first launch it, it tells you to check the "use this application as default" box, and makes you select toddler lock.

So, it's not really blocking the Home button at all, it's just setting itself up as the default broadcast receiver for:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

When you launch Toddler Lock, it probably sets an internal flag, and if you press the home button, it just brings the window to the front. If the flag is not set, it probably launches Launcher explicitly.

I hope that makes sense. It's just a theory, but I'm almost 100% sure that's how it's done.

Comment: I have just tried it and even though it does not really block the Home Button, I will have to use it as the last option if I can't disable the Home Button. Thank you for your help =D